# Symfony 2.7 I need two selectors

Tags: symfony

Symfony 2 I need two selectors, i have this code

```
use Ct\CiudadBundle\Entity\Departamento;

use Ct\CiudadBundle\Entity\Factura;

use Ct\CiudadBundle\Entity\Provincia;

class FacturaType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            //->add('nombre')
            ->add('nit')
            ->add('fidProvincia')
            /*->add('fidDepartamento', 'entity', array(
                'class'       => 'CtCiudadBundle:Departamento',
                'placeholder' => 'Elije el departamento',
            )); */
        ;


        $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();

        $refreshStates = function ($form, $departamento) use ($factory) {
            $form->add($factory->createNamed('entity','provincia', null, array(
                'class'         => 'CtCiudadBundle:Provincia',
                'property'      => 'nombre',
                'empty_value'   => '-- Select a provincia --',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($departamento) {
                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('provincia')
                        ->innerJoin('provincia.departamento', 'departamento');

                    if ($departamento instanceof Departamento) {
                        $qb->where('provincia.departamento = :departamento')
                            ->setParameter('departamento', $departamento);
                    } elseif (is_numeric($departamento)) {
                        $qb->where('departamento.id = :departamento')
                            ->setParameter('departamento', $departamento);
                    } else {
                        $qb->where('departamento.nombre = :departamento')
                            ->setParameter('departamento', null);
                    }

                    return $qb;
               })
           ));
        };

        $setDepartamento = function ($form, $departamento) use ($factory) {
            $form->add($factory->createNamed('entity', 'departamento', null, array(
                'class'         => 'CtCiudadBundle:Departamento', 
                'property'      => 'nombre', 
                'property_path' => false,
                'empty_value'   => '-- Select a country --',
                'data'          => $country,
            )));
        };

         $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (DataEvent $event) use ($refreshStates, $setDepartamento) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if ($data == null) {
                return;
            }

            if ($data instanceof Factura) {
                $departamento = ($data->getId()) ? $data->getProvincia()->getDepartamento() : null ;
                $refreshStates($form, $departamento);
                $setDepartamento($form, $departamento);
            }
        });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function (DataEvent $event) use ($refreshStates) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if(array_key_exists('departamento', $data)) {
                $refreshStates($form, $data['departamento']);
            }
        });
```

and I have this issue

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Ct\CiudadBundle\Form\FacturaType::Ct\CiudadBundle\Form{closure}()
>   must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent,
>   instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent given

How can I deal with it??
help me please...!!

Comment: Can you please post *all* of your `use` statements at the top of the file?

Comment: Your `function (DataEvent $event)`'s should changed to `function (FormEvent $event)` as that is what the event dispatcher will be injecting.

Comment: ty it works prefectily